Is there a way to copy/paste an edge pattern to another face on the same object?
On the left is a pattern that I want to copy to the face on the right. I've tried ctrl C and V and it doesn't work. I've also tried using things like snapping and shrinkwrap and they don't seem to work either. Another thing to note is that these rectangles are the inside of a cylinder so they go in a circle and the rotation of the face changes. Is there a faster way to copy the pattern to the face on the right without recreating it?


Duplicate (shift+d), position, merge.


Subdivide the top or bottom edges all around so you have center points (these points will be your snapping points)
Set the 3d cursor to the center of the cylinder (select a bottom or top face, shift+s, cursor to selected)
Set the "pivot point" option to 3d cursor (image below)
Set the snap option to vertices (image below)
Select the entire face loop where you want the pattern and delete "faces" (you will replace these faces with the pattern faces, you don't want duplication)
Select the pattern faces
Duplicate (shift+d) and don't place it!!!
While in the middle of the duplication, rotate R around Z
Use B to snap from top vertice to top vertice and place it (B, select top vertice on pattern, select top vertice on where it will go)
Select all vertices (A) and merge (M) by distance.

You can then gradually increase the selection to duplicate 2, 4, 8 patterns at once if you want.


You're a hero bro, although I already brute forced it but thank god I know the way now!

@KhoiTran Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, please don't just reply "Thanks" as a comment, instead upvote the post that helped you. If you feel it completely solved your issue consider marking it as accepted.
